# Call Controller Method From Scope Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dynamic, controller

**JQuery to  Directive**

I want to call a method from the scope of this directive but can't seem to work it out (if possible).

$("my-directive").first().scope().loadData();

**Directive Looks Something Like This**

I would like to call the loadData function from the directive code below.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "..."
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var self = this;
            $scope.loadData = function () {
               ... 
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope is accessible **inside** the directive

You can get any child of the element of which directive is applied and get scope of it.

```
$('my-directive').first().children(":first").scope().loadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Strajk's answer is correct!

**When Code is Added Dynamically setTimeout Needed**

In the following example detail row has a nested directive (random-testees). I get the scope from that to dynamically compile the directive (dynamic and late-bound). The **setTimeout** is needed because it seems to take a bit before the

```
var detailRow = e.detailRow;

// Compile the directive for dyanmic content. 
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element(detailRow).scope();
    $compile(detailRow)(scope);
});

// Get some data from directive. 
var testId = detailRow.find("random-testees").attr("testid");

// Wait, and call method on the directive. 
setTimeout(function () {
    var randomTesteesScope = $("random-testees").first().children(":first").scope();
    randomTesteesScope.loadTestees(this);
}.bind(testId),200);
```

**Not Very Confident About This**

This seems a little brittle since I was getting mixed results with a 100 ms timeout sometimes and error when the **randomTesteesScope** returned undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I think my code above is good only for inspecting webapp from console... I wouldn't use it in app's source code.

Comment: @Strajk, but I don't have a choice here. I need to dynamically load the directive content. And then call a method on it.